# How to flush/clear buffer in a socket in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

How do I flush a socket in python3?

I'm looking to do something like this

```
def clear_buffer(sock):
    try:
        while sock.recv(1024): pass
    except:
        pass
```

or

```
def clear_buffer(sock):
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
```

After attempting to run these two functions neither seem to break the while loop and/or flush out the socket from incoming data. How do I conditionally do something when the socket has stopped receiving data?

Comment: maybe you should use timeout to raise error when it wait too long for data or stop waiting for data - [settimeout](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout). Or you should use module [select](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html) to check if there are data before you use `read()`

Comment: I've found away around this by sending a flag containing characters to break the while loop when the socket is finished sending data. I'd rather not do this differently though so I don't have to set flags whenever I'm streaming data etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
        while run_network:
            recv = True
            data = b''


            try:
                while recv:
                    try:
                        packet = socket.recv(10240)
                        if packet:
                            data += packet
                        else:
                            recv = False
                        try:
                            pickle.loads(data)
                            recv = False
                        except:
                            recv = True

                    except ConnectionResetError:
                       
                            print(f"{client} has disconnected........")
                            break
                    except ConnectionError:
                     **strong text**
                            print(f"{client}has a Connection Error.....")
                            break
```

Comment: Can you offer an explanation, instead of just including code?